# Apply jScrollPane on JQGrid - issue with horizontal scrolling

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jquery-jscrollpane

I am trying to use [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) with my JQGrid. I need both horizontal and vertical scrolling on the grid with jScrollPane. The behaviour I am trying to achieve is,

- The vertical scroll bar must scroll only the body of the Grid
- The horizontal scroll bar should scroll both body and header.

This is possible using default scroll bars. But when I apply jScrollPane, the horizontal scroll bar scrolls only the body of the grid while the header remains fixed. Below is a sampl of my code.

```
<body>
<table id="list4"></table>
<script type="text/javascript" language=javascript>
var mydata = [
    { id: "1", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00",  tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "2", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "5", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "6", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "7", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "8", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "9", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "10", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "12", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "13", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "14", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "15", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "16", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "17", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "18", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "19", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "11", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "20", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "23", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "24", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "25", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "26", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "27", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "28", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "29", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" }
    ];
    jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: mydata,
        width: 200,
        height: 250,
        colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
        colModel: [
    { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "int" },
    { name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 90, sorttype: "date" },
    { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100 },
    { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
    { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
    { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
    { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false }
],
        multiselect: true,
        caption: "Manipulating Array Data",
        shrinkToFit: false,
        loadComplete: function () {
            $('#gview_list4>div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').jScrollPane();
        }
    });

</script>
</body>
```

I am setting the jSrollPane during loadcomplete on bDiv. I have also tried applying it on the outer div element that encloses both hdiv and bdiv. But that does not work. Can anyone please suggest a solution to this problem? Is there anything I can do to get the desired behaviour?

Thanks in Advance :) !!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that this could be the error: `$('#gview_list4>div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').jScrollPane();`

Try changing to this:

```
$('div.summaries .ui-jqgrid-bdiv').jScrollPane({ 
    scrollbarWidth: 15, scrollbarMargin: 0 
});
```

and on HTML one structure like this:

```
 <div id="summaries" style="text-align: center;" class="summaries">
    <div id="summaries_container">
          <table id = "gview_list4"></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this  did not fix my issue. The solution mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505536/how-to-use-jscrollpane-with-jqgrid?answertab=votes#tab-top fixed my issue. I had to bind the grid header to the scroll event of the grid body.

Answer (score 0):

The solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505536/how-to-use-jscrollpane-with-jqgrid?answertab=votes#tab-top)  fixed my issue. I had to bind the grid header to the scroll event of the grid body.