# How to use jScrollPane with jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

How to use JScrollPane with jqgrid? I tried to use it but the headers are not moving. Here is my code.

```
       gridComplete:function(){
$('#gview_mygrid >div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').jScrollPane({ showArrows: true, scrollbarWidth: 17, arrowSize: 17, scrollbarMargin: 0 });}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out..
Here is the working code.
In the markup

```
 <div id="container" >  
        <table id="list"><tr><td/></tr></table>
        <div id="pager"></div>
  </div>
```

IN Java script, We have to bind the header (class .ui-jqgrid-hbox) also to scroll

```
gridComplete:function(){
             var table_header = $('#container').find('.ui-jqgrid-hbox').css("position","relative");
             $('#container').find('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').bind('jsp-scroll-x', function(event, scrollPositionX, isAtLeft, isAtRight) {
                            table_header.css('right', scrollPositionX);
                           }).jScrollPane({
                             showArrows: true, 
                            autoReinitialise: true,
                            horizontalDragMaxWidth: 30,
                            verticalDragMaxHeight: 30           
                        });
                     }
```